# preg_replace with some conditions

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, replace, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace a string that may appear multiple times. It starts and ends with a specific string:

```
some text
more text here
[li]......[/li]
[li]......[/li]
[li]......[/li]
```

Can I check the string before **[li]** and the **[li]** if before **[li]** is a string but not a **[/li]** then replace it with the same pattern except the newline is doubled with a regex?

What i want to check:

```
some strings 
\n // Replace this one
[li]some strings[/li] \n 
[li]some strings[/li] \n // This one is not replaced, because the string before this [li] were [/li]
[li]some strings[/li] \n
some strings
```

if the condition is fulfilled then make it like this

```
some strings 
\n\n // With this one instead
[li]some strings[/li] \n
[li]some strings[/li] \n
[li]some strings[/li] \n
some strings
```

This is my code so far, but i can't get what i want:

```
$data = preg_replace("/(.*)\([\n]/\[li\]/s", "[result]", $data);
```

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/r/2lz8x9/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew wow, it works like a magic. it's like what i wanted to and it gives me the explanation, thanks!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and can you please put it on the answer? so I can mark as done

Comment: Done, please see the explanation below.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
'~(\[li\b[^]]*].*?\[\/li])(?:\R*(?1))*(*SKIP)(*F)|(\R)~s'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2lz8x9/2)

- `(\[li\b[^]]*].*?\[\/li])` - Group 1: `[li...]...[/li]` substring (note that `.*?` with `s` modifier will match across lines and will match any 0+ chars other than line break as few as possible, so it won't overflow across multiple `li` elements.)
- `(?:\R*(?1))*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `\R*` - zero or more line breaks
  - `(?1)`  - the same pattern as in Group 1 (see above)
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - remove the match value from the buffer
- `|` - or
- `(\R)` - match and capture a line break into Group 2.

The replacement is a value from Group 2 times two (`$1$1` where `$1` references the value stored in Group 2).